Is it possible for two diagonal matrices over a commutative ring with no nontrivial idempotents to be similar without being permutation-similar?
The definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors could be generalized to matrices over commutative rings that are not necessarily fields.
That is, if $A \in M_{n \times n}(R)$ and $0 \ne v \in M_{n \times 1}(R)$ satisfy the equation $Av=\lambda{v}$ for some $\lambda \in R$, then $\lambda$ and $v$ are called an eigenvalue and eigenvector of $A$ respectively, even if $R$ is not a field.
With this definition, it is still true that $A$ is similar (or conjugate) to a diagonal matrix (i.e., $A=PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and some diagonal matrix $D$) if and only if the $R$-module $R^n$ is freely generated by eigenvectors of $A$.
But is possible for two diagonal matrices $D$ and $D'$ over a commutative ring with no nontrivial idempotents to be similar without being permutation-similar (i.e., $D=PD'P^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$, but $P$ cannot be chosen to be a permutation matrix)?
The question has a trivial answer in the case of commutative rings with nontrivial idempotents (which split as nontrivial direct products). Namely, given diagonal matrices $D_1$ over $R_1$ and $D_2$ over $R_2$ and two distinct permutation matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$, the image of $(P_1D_1P_1^{-1}, P_2D_2P_2^{-1})$ under the obvious isomorphism $M_{n \times n}(R_1) \times M_{n \times n}(R_2) \cong M_{n \times n}(R_1 \times R_2)$ is similar but not necessarily permutation-similar to the image of $(D_1, D_2)$. For a concrete example, $\begin{pmatrix} e&0\\0&1-e \end{pmatrix}$ is similar but not permutation-similar to $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ via the invertible matrix $\begin{pmatrix} e&1-e\\1-e&e \end{pmatrix}$ for any nontrivial idempotent $e$.
Over commutative rings, diagonal matrices could have more eigenvalues than just the diagonal entries. For example, the identity matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has $3$ as an eigenvalue with $\begin{pmatrix} 2\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ (or $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 2\\2 \end{pmatrix}$) as a corresponding eigenvector. But the identity matrix is always similar only to itself anyway, so that is a dumb example.
For the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 5&0\\0&7 \end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, although the traces, determinants, and characteristic polynomials all match, the matrices are still provably not similar, because any matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ for which $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&3 \end{pmatrix}P=P\begin{pmatrix} 5&0\\0&7 \end{pmatrix}$ must have $a, d \in 2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ and $b, c \in 4\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, making the determinant $ad-bc \in 4\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, which does not contain any units.

Restricting to 2x2 matrices, let $D$ and $D'$ be diagonal matrices having main diagonal entries $a_1,a_2$ and $b_1,b_2$, respectively. Let $P=\begin{pmatrix} p_{11}&p_{21}\\p_{12}&p_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ be such that $p_{11}p_{22}-p_{12}p_{21}=1$. Here, the $a_i,b_i$ and $p_{ij}$ denote indeterminates over $\mathbb{Z}$. As a simple calculation shows, in order that $D'=PDP^{-1}$, or $D'P=PD$, one needs the equalities $b_jp_{ij}=a_ip_{ij}$ for every pair $(i,j)$ with $1\le i,j\le2$.
So taking $R=\mathbb{Z}[a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,p_{11},p_{12},p_{21},p_{22}]/I$, where the ideal $I$ is generated by the polynomials $p_{11}p_{22}-p_{12}p_{21}-1$ and $(a_i-b_j)p_{ij}$ (for all $1\le i,j\le2$), the resulting matrices $D$ and $D'$ are similar over $R$ (even by a unimodular matrix $P$). But they are not permutation-similar. For if they were, $a_1,a_2$ would be a permutation of $b_1,b_2$, and that clearly does not follow from the relations in $I$.
Less clearly, this ring $R$ shouldn't have any nontrivial idempotents. But I do not have a proof.

If Macaulay2 is correct (!), $I$ is an intersection of three primes, say $P_1,P_2,P_3$, so $R\hookrightarrow R/p_1\times R/p_2\times R/p_3$, where $p_i=P_i/I$. We also have $p_1+p_2\ne R$ and $p_1+p_3\ne R$. (Btw, $p_2+p_3=R$, but this doesn't matter.) The idempotent $e\in R$ corresponds to an $(a,b,c)$ in the direct product. The elements $a,b,c$ are also idempotent, so these have to be $0$ or $1$. But if $a=0$, then $b=c=0$ and if $a=1$, then $b=c=1$. (This follows from the previous remark on the sum of primes.) We get that $R$ has only trivial idempotents.

@user26857: very nice.
